# Cython cannot refer to a declared type in a cdef class if there is a property with that same name?

Tags: cython

I have some complex generated cython code that wraps a C++ library.

For one of the C++ libraries I wrap, I get a really hard to understand
error. The following is a minimum reproducible example

`bad.pxd`:

```
cdef class Foo:
    pass

cdef class Bar:
    pass
```

`bad.pyx`:

```
cdef class Bar:
    x = {}

    Bar.x['Foo'] = Foo

    @property
    def Foo(self):
        pass

    @Foo.setter
    def Foo(self, val):
        pass
```

The error from the cython compiler:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cdef class Bar:
    x = {}

    Bar.x['Foo'] = Foo
                ^
------------------------------------------------------------

bad.pyx:4:19: 'Foo' is not a constant, variable or function identifier
```

This compiles fine if I comment out `Bar.x['Foo'] = Foo` or if I comment
out the property.

It seems like you cannot refer to a typename if you also use that name
as a property. It seems ok to do this if it is a method, but not a
property.

Does this violate some rule in Cython, or is this more likely a bug?

I realize that the right answer is "don't do that", but unfortunately, 
I do not control the names that result in this admittedly odd class
definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best workaround would be

```
Bar.x['Foo'] = globals()['Foo'].
```

Even in some of the cases you mention work they don't do what you'd expect: if `Foo` is a method then the dict ends up as:

```
{'Foo': <method 'Foo' of 'modulename.Bar' objects>}
```

(i.e. not the Python behaviour).

---

It probably is a bug, but I doubt if it's easy or high priority to fix since it's a combination of lookup being resolved at compile-time and properties not being assignable. The former is almost certainly known and probably unfixable. Bugs can be [reported on the issue tracker](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues).

Comment: Thanks David. I was considering mangling the property names and using `PyObject_GenericSetAttr` to drop them onto the class. Using `globals()['Foo']` seems like a much better idea